# Styling a link on hover - with Radium in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been looking for an answer here and in the documentation, but I can't seem to find it. Here's the [Radium documentation](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium).

I'd like to know if there's a way to style links in React? Specifically a, a:hover, a:visited etc.

**Example:**

```
var React = require("react");
var Radium = require('radium');
var Link = require('react-router').Link

var Header = React.createClass({
    render: function(){

        var styles={
            links: {
                ":hover": {color: "red", textDecoration: "none"}
            }
        }

        return(     
            <div style={[styles.links]}>
                <Link to="/photos">Photos</Link>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Radium(Header);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do anything with React's `style` property that you can't do with standard HTML inline styles. This includes using CSS pseudo classes.

Instead, assign a class to your React component via the `className` property and apply the styles to this class in a CSS style-sheet:

```
return(     
    <div className="my-link">
        <Link to="/photos">Photos</Link>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Damn. I totally tried to over engineer this one. I completely blanked out on the classes. Thanks for pointing it out man.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the use of Radium's visited plugin:

https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium/commit/87457d036c63312185d0148eb5b8a3cc48906e87

You wrap your component in `<StyleRoot>`
and write your styles like so:

```
myLink = {
  color: '#fff',
  ':visited': {
     color: 'purple'
  }
}
```